# Get Azure Automation Account name from a Virtual Machine name using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am working on a script to help automate checks on our VMs. Is there a PowerShell command that will identify the automation account a VM is running under? I have the log analytics workspace ID and name.

I am wanting the automation name that a VM is using

Comment: Kindly share the script, what you have tried?

Comment: You need to be an admin and get the process owner : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960800/get-process-and-process-owner

Comment: To get the name of the Azure Automation account that a VM is running under, you can use the following PowerShell command:


`(Get-AzVM -Name <VMName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>).Tags['AutomationAccount']`

Answer (score 0):

To find the Azure Automation account linked to a specific VM via PowerShell, you need to correlate the information between your Log Analytics workspace, the Automation Account, and the VM. Typically, a VM isn't "under" an Automation Account directly, but they might be connected through solutions like Update Management, which uses both Log Analytics and Automation Account. Since you already have the Log Analytics workspace ID and name, ensure that the VM is reporting to this workspace. Look for any Automation Accounts linked to this Log Analytics workspace. This linkage is usually established when you enable features like Update Management on the VM.

example script-

```
#Login to Azure if not already logged in
Connect-AzAccount

#Get the Log Analytics workspace - replace 'YourWorkspaceName' and 'YourResourceGroup' with your actual values
$workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -ResourceGroupName "YourResourceGroup" -Name "YourWorkspaceName"

#List all Automation Accounts in your subscription
$automationAccounts = Get-AzAutomationAccount

#Loop through each Automation Account to find if it's linked to your Log Analytics workspace
foreach ($account in $automationAccounts) {
    # Get the account details
    $accountDetails = Get-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $account.ResourceGroupName -Name $account.AutomationAccountName
    
    # Check if this account is linked to the Log Analytics workspace
    if ($accountDetails.LinkedWorkspaceId -eq $workspace.ResourceId) {
        Write-Output "VM is likely managed by Automation Account: $($account.AutomationAccountName)"
    }
}
```

[image]

This script checks each Automation Account in your subscription to see if it's linked to the specified Log Analytics workspace.

Another way-
To get the name of the Azure Automation account that a VM is running under, you can use the following PowerShell command:

```
(Get-AzVM -Name <VMName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>).Tags['AutomationAccount']
```

This approach assumes that the virtual machine has been tagged with the 'AutomationAccount' tag, which contains the name of the Azure Automation account it is associated with.
[image]

Replace  `<VMName>`  with the name of the VM you want to check and  `<ResourceGroupName>`  with the name of the resource group it belongs to. This command retrieves the value of the 'AutomationAccount' tag that is assigned to the VM, which should contain the name of the Azure Automation account it is running under.

To find the details of a linked Log Analytics workspace for an Azure Automation account using PowerShell, you can use the Get-AzAutomationAccount cmdlet.
Workaround- you edit your script so that it can access the information via Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template properties or potentially by direct REST API calls.

example-

```
#Login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

#Replace these with your actual resource group and automation account names
$resourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroupName"
$automationAccountName = "YourAutomationAccountName"

#Construct the REST API URL
$subscriptionId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/$automationAccountName?api-version=2015-10-31"

#Invoke the REST API call to get the automation account details
$response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url

#Convert the response to a PowerShell object
$automationAccountDetails = ConvertFrom-Json $response.Content

#Extract the linked workspace ID from the details
$linkedWorkspaceId = $automationAccountDetails.properties.LinkedWorkspaceId

#Output the linked workspace ID
$linkedWorkspaceId
```

References:

- [Manage your Azure Automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/delete-account#manage-your-azure-automation-account)
- [Phase 1: Prerequisite planning for Azure server management services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/manage/azure-server-management/prerequisites#create-a-workspace-and-automation-account)
- [Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960800/get-process-and-process-owner) suggested by [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)

Comment: This is extremely helpful. The only thing that I can't figure out, $accountDetails.LinkedWorkspaceId seems to be nonexistent. I can see clearing in the portal that the 2 are linked, but does not populate in PowerShell

Comment: If you're unable to find the LinkedWorkspaceId after these steps, as a workaround, you could manually check the Azure Portal for the linked workspace ID of the Automation Account and then take the [value](https://i.imgur.com/vdNiCPL.png) from the portal directly and update your script directly with the value or use the example script I shared above.